# If we've got 10 coupons, what is expected number of different ones if there are 25 different types

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I can't figure out this problem :

> There are 25 different types of coupon, all equally probable to get. If we have got 10 coupons, what is expected number of different coupons between them?

Solution is : E(x) = 8.38

Comment: Hint:  let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for coupon $C_i$.  Thus, $X_i=1$ if $C_i$ appears in your group, $0$ otherwise.  By linearity of expectation, your answer $E=\sum E[X_i]=25p$  where $p$ is the probability that a given coupon appears in your group.  Not hard to compute $p$.

Comment: @lulu I feel retarded, I simply can't fully figure this out. I'm constantly thinking p is 1/25 or P(x = 1) where x is B(10,1/25) none of those give correct solution and I can't seem to understand the problem.

Comment: Oh, I got it! No need for reply! Thanks for your tip :D

Comment: Please mind the ableist language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Stirling numbers we get

$$\frac{1}{25^{10}} \sum_{q=1}^{10} q\times
{25\choose q} \times {10\brace q} \times q!$$

which gives the expectation

$${\frac {31964050675249}{3814697265625}}
\approx 8.379184100.$$

What we  have done here  is choose the  $q$ different values  from the
$25$  different ones  where we  can  obviously represent  at most  ten
different values. We  then partition the $10$ slots  into $q$ sets and
choose a permutation of the $q$  that gives the value assigned to each
set. Finally multiply by $q$  because we are computing the expectation
of the number of different values which is precisely $q.$

Observe also that the probability of a coupon number $p$ not appearing
is $$\frac{24^{10}}{25^{10}}$$
which yields for the expectation

$$\sum_{p=1}^{25} \left(1-\frac{24^{10}}{25^{10}}\right)
= {\frac {31964050675249}{3814697265625}}$$

the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable $=1$ if the $i^{th}$ coupon is present, and $=0$ otherwise.

Then $P[i^{th}$ coupon is present$] = [1 - (\frac{24}{25})^{10}]$
Now the expectation of an indicator r.v.  is just the probability of the event it indicates, so $E[X_i] = [1 - (\frac{24}{25})^{10}]$

By linearity of expectation we have *expectation of sum = sum of expectations*,
$E[\sum{(X_i)}] = \sum{E(X_i)} = 25[1 - (\frac{24}{25})^{10}] \approx 8.38$